# Отсортировать и вывести данные

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

Есть массив таких объектов:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "update": 1613080786851,
    "group": "group 1",
    "subgroup": "subgroup 1",
    "pInfo":
    {
        "pName": "Oliver_Patterson"
    }
}
```

Поле update указывает на последнее обновление информации, если `new Date().getTime() - account.update > 120`, то это будет значит, что он не активен (это потребуется дальше).

account: объект аккаунта выше, idleTime: `new Date().getTime() - account.update`.
Нужно отсортировать и вывести в таком формате:

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list__dropdown list__dropdown--hide">[Group: ${account.group}] Активно: ... (сколько активно в group)/... (сколько всего в group)</li>

    <li class="list-items">
        <ul class="list">
            <li class="list__dropdown list__dropdown--hide">[Subgroup: ${account.subgroup}] Активно: ... (сколько активно в subgroup)/... (сколько всего в subgroup)</li>
    
            <li class="list-items">
                <ul class="list">
                    <li class="list__item">
                        <span ${idleTime > WAITS_IDLE ? 'class="className"' : ''}></span>
                        (${account.id}): ${account.pInfo.pName} ${idleTime > WAITS_IDLE ? `(Upd: ${idleTime} с. назад)` : ``}
                    </li>

                    ... (новый li с информацией пользователя)
                </ul>
            </li>
            ... (новый li > ul с subgroup)
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
... (новый ul с group)
```

---

Я уже сижу часа два ломаю голову, как это лучше сделать. Проблема скорее в подсчете данных и выводом.
Так же желательно, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было вывести отдельно всех "юзеров" subgroup и сортировать.

Проект сделан с использованием express (сервер), ejs (шаблоны, но толком я и не нашел применения).
Я очень надеюсь на вашу помощь и направление, помогу любой дополнительной информацией.

Answer (score 1):

```
const getActiveUserLengthInGroup = (arr, group_name = null, subgroup_name = null) => {
    const isActive = (last_update) => {
        return (new Date().getTime() - last_update) > 120
    }

    let users_in_group = [...arr].filter((user) => {
        return group_name ? user.group === group_name : user.subgroup === subgroup_name;
    })

    let active_users_in_group = [...users_in_group].filter((user) => {
        return isActive(user.update)
    })

    return [users_in_group.length, active_users_in_group.length]
}


const [group1_count, group1_active] = getActiveUserLengthInGroup(array, 'group 1')
```

Вот есть функция getActiveUserLengthInGroup, принимает массив всех пользователей, имя группы, имя субгруппы. Возвращает массив из двух элементов: первый элемент это количество юзеров из заданной групы, второй элемент количество активных юзеров из данной группы.

Если нужно и субгруппы получить данные, мы передаем вторым параметром `null`, а третьим название субгруппы.

```
const [subgroup3_group_count, subgroup3_group_active] = getActiveUserLengthInGroup(array, null, 'subgroup 3')
```

И потом уже выводим в шаблон:

```
<li class="list__dropdown list__dropdown--hide">[SubGroup: ${account.subgroup}] Активно: ${subgroup3_group_active} ${subgroup3_group_count}</li>
```

Comment: Очень даже не плохо, но теперь вопрос, как это все вывести правильно. Чтобы был ul с первым li в котором группа, вторым li: ul с li в котором название под группы и еще одним li в котором содержимое подгруппы и нужно вывести все подгруппы данной группы.